# How to send reference of AppDelegate to Viewcontroller subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, appdelegate

I've subclassed a viewController class, like this...

.h file

```
#import "GADBannerView.h"

@interface ViewController : SPViewController
{
    GADBannerView *bannerView;
}

@property GADBannerView *bannerView;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize bannerView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 50)];

    // Replace this ad unit ID with your own ad unit ID.
    self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-LONG ID HERE";
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    // Requests test ads on devices you specify. Your test device ID is printed to the console when
    // an ad request is made.
    request.testDevices = @[ GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"SIM ID HERE" ];
    [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And in my AppDelegate I've got this

```
 _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];


    [_viewController startWithRoot:[Game class] supportHighResolutions:YES doubleOnPad:YES];

    [_window setRootViewController:_viewController];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

All works fine, but I need to be able to put in a switch in the ViewController subclass, to whether the AdMob ad is set up or not, a Boolean which will be set in a plist, which is accessed via the AppDelegate, so I need to send a reference of the AppDelegate to my subclassed ViewController, so I can then do something like

```
if ([[appDelegate.coreData objectForKey:@"AdMob"] boolValue] == YES) {
       //Admob setup here
    }
```

in my ViewController subclass. How can I get a reference to the AppDelegate in my ViewController Subclass?

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
// ...
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Cool, what if I wanted to send a reference to another class though to my ViewController subclass?

Comment: That depends on what class and how its objects are created.  (`sharedApplication` is a singleton object, so it's available anywhere.)

Comment: But what I don't really understand is how you send a reference of a class (just a standard class) to my ViewController subclass, when you instantiate it, because it's calling the Init on the parent class, so I don't know how to get something through to the subclass.

Comment: You may need to give an actual example.  You're saying 'class' but I suspect you mean 'object'.  If you **really** mean 'class', it's simply what you already do with the `GADBannerView` class.

Comment: You're probably right I mean object, how would I send a reference to a class through to my subclass?

Comment: I suggest putting up a new question with code that demonstrates what you're attempting.  There's no "one size fits all" answer to what you're asking and some code would clarify the question.  (If you do that, add a link here to the new question and I'll take a look.)